# Triggering the end of a while loop using the completion of SKAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to use a "while loop" while my `SKSpritenode` is animating and I want to trigger the end of the `SKAction` to trigger the end of the loop. This is my attempt

```
while (orgNode.hasActions) {
   //render the background
}
```

what I want to do is create a bottom up sweep effect that changes the sprite nodes texture underneath the originNode's position, so that the user sees the sweeping motion of the node changing the background color.

Comment: can you explain more clearly what effect you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `update` or `didEvaluateActions` function of the `SKScene` if you want to update the node every frame. `didEvaluateActions` function is called in each frame after all the `SKActions` are evaluated. The `update` function is called before all actions are evaluated.

```
override func didEvaluateActions() {
    if node.hasActions()
    {
        println("Running Action")
    }
}
```

The following image shows which all functions are called in each frame and in what order.

[image]

For more information : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html